# react-native android assembleDebug log: Unknown source file : warning: string 'catalyst_debugjs' has no default translation

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

Testing a fresh react-native project: react-native init

react-native run-android log:

```
...
:app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
Unknown source file : warning: string 'catalyst_debugjs' has no default translation.
Unknown source file : warning: string 'catalyst_element_inspector' has no default translation.
Unknown source file : warning: string 'catalyst_jsload_error' has no default translation.
Unknown source file : warning: string 'catalyst_jsload_message' has no default translation.
Unknown source file : warning: string 'catalyst_jsload_title' has no default translation.
Unknown source file : warning: string 'catalyst_reloadjs' has no default translation.
Unknown source file : warning: string 'catalyst_settings' has no default translation.
Unknown source file : warning: string 'catalyst_settings_title' has no default translation.

:app:generateDebugSources
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
...
```

Though the build succeeds but this warning is driving me crazy, any idea?

RN: v0.18.1
OS: Mac 10.11.3

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got rid of the warning by updating the build gradle version in `build.gradle` file.

Change

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
```

To

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm at 2.2.3 and seeing the same symptom. Trying to figure out what it really is...